# Google maps doesn't load prop

Tags: android, maps, genymotion

i have followed the google tutorial for using google maps and every thing is fine except that the map doesn't load prob on genymotion emulator

this is my mainfest

```
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="*************************************"/>
    <activity
```

and this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

please respond asap !!!

Comment: hav u checked with any device except emulator and genymotion emulator?

Comment: check with device whether map is loading or not..If it works fine means you r emulator has to update

Comment: so i have to change the api key from debug to release right????

Comment: No need...how many keys you have extracted for your app from google?

Comment: In genymotion emulator map will get load, only if the API key which extracted from your PC's SHA must be present in your manifest.

Comment: 2 one for an old app and the current one

Comment: Hav you tried with both keys in device or emulator?

Comment: i don't think that the code is the issue

Comment: it's showing grid now???
what to do?????

Comment: I am not saying about your code..I am saying its coz of API key...If you are in developing stage the API key which you extracted from your PC is present in your manifest...Orelse have u update google play services ?

Comment: it's present and i updated the google play services

Comment: If that API key is generated from your PC's SHA key?

Comment: i have an idea 
how about making a new api key and making a new app????

Comment: yes it is the same one

Comment: i solved it 
i installed the google store on my genymotion emulator and installed the google maps but didn't update it
i updated it now and that solved my problem thank's alot

Comment: hmm welcome!!!!I will post my answer you just accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are under developing your project, the API key which you are currently using must be generated from your PC's SHA key.

If it is fine, there could problem in your Play services. So, the Google Play Services must be in upto date.

Thanks!!